# how to color the background of a ::before element that represents an arrow in a timeline

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a jquery plugin that provides a timeline. I want to be able to color the background of the little arrow that goes with each timeline element.

https://jsfiddle.net/LNMSchneiderman/Ljfw9xg4/2/

```
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline__wrap">
    <div class="timeline__items">
    
      <div class="timeline__item ">
        <div class="timeline__content news">
          <h2>Jan. 5, 2020</h2>
          <p>news item</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__content news">
          <h2>Jan. 31, 2020</h2>
          <p>news item</p>
        </div>
      </div>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.timeline').timeline({
      mode:'vertical',
    });
```

The pseudo element for the arrow is created like this:

```
.timeline__content:before {
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    right: -12px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.timeline__content:after, .timeline__content:before {
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
}
```

But nothing I do seems to change the background color of that little arrow. Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: .news::after {
  border-left-color: #e8f5e9;
}

Comment: @Kyle: that was the answer, short and sweet, with the correct class that needed to be changed! Can you enter it separately as an answer?

Comment: @LauraNMS you can accept the other person who answered. They took the time to explain it a little more.

Comment: @Kyle - your answer was more helpful to me, since it specified which class needed the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth looking in your browser's dev tools, inspecting the arrow element to see exactly how it is being formed and colored.

Here is the before and after from your fiddle:

[image]

before you can see the color as a lightish gray. I changed that to red:
[image]

So as you can see you need to change the border-left setting.

Note: border-left-color does not work by itself in this situation, change the color in the border shorthand version:

```
border-left: 12px solid red;
```